# Can't parse value to Vue2Editor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vuejs2

I'm using [vue2editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-editor?activeTab=readme) and in the edit page I'm trying to parse current content value to the vue2editor since we editing but this is not working, The vue2editor still appears with blank content like I did not parse any value.

Below is the template code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <v-row>
        <div>
          <vue-2-editor
            id="privacyPolicy"
            v-model="privacyPolicy"
          ></vue-2-editor>
        </div>
      </v-row>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";

import Vue2Editor from "../../components/vue2-editor.vue";

export default {
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  components: {
    Vue2Editor,
  },
  data: () => ({
    itemId: 0,
    _privacyPolicy: "",
    privacyPolicy: "",
  }),
  mounted() {
    let privacyPolicy = document.getElementById("privacyPolicy");

    privacyPolicyController.readOne().then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.itemId = data.result.id;
        privacyPolicy.value = 'Current Content';
        this.privacyPolicy = 'Current Content';
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      let privacyPolicy = document.getElementById("privacyPolicy");

      privacyPolicy.textContent = this._privacyPolicy;

      if (this.privacyPolicy === "") {
        alert("Privacy Policy is required!");
      } else {
        let formData = {
          privacyPolicy: this.privacyPolicy,
        };

        console.log(formData);

        await privacyPolicyController.addNew(formData);
        return await this.$router.push({ name: "Privacy Policy" });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

What I'm I missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `privacyPolicy` definition in `computed` object instead of `data()`

That way, when the value changes, the component is re-rendered